# Full Oauth2 Authentication Flow with Vue.js Client and Express.js Server Using Passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, vue.js, passport.js

I have a problem understanding how to use the Bearer Access Token received from an OAuth2 authentication flow.

In my case the client is Vue.js, the server is Express.js and the authentication middle layer is Passport.js.

**The configuration of Passport and authentication flow is standard:**

- It is an OAuth2 Passport strategy (in my case Asana)
- On the server there is routing /auth/asana that calls passport.authenticate.
- On the server there is routing /auth/asana/cb for the call back from Asana.
- And there is a success URL pointing back to the client.

**Step by step this is what I do:**

1. On the client/home user clicks "Authenticate" and I do a redirect to server/auth/asana.
2. server/auth/asana using Passport.js redirect to Asana so user can authenticate.
3. server/auth/asana/cb receives the authenticated user back from Asana.
4. server/auth/asana/cb redirect the user back to client/home.
5. From client/home I now want to start using the API to fetch data.

**Here is 3 questions:**

1. On the server (Express.js where Passport.js is used), how to I get the Bearer Access Token?
2. On the client (Vue.js), where should the Bearer Access Token be stored so it can be used in requests against the external API (in this case Asana)?
3. How should the Bearer Access Token be transferred from the server (Express.js) to the client (Vue.js)?

Please note that I've read lots of articles on this and the steps 1 to 4 is fine, the code to authenticate etc. works well. But it seems I am missing something fundamental here since none of the articles explain how to actually use the Bearer Access Token once authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the Asana API documentation](https://developers.asana.com/docs/#oauth), the `access_token` shall be passed into the `Authorization` header, like the following:

```
curl https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/me \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

It's the standard way of passing an access token for OAuth2 based API. If you still struggle to get it through, you can use an API-tool (like [Pizzly](https://github.com/bearer/pizzly)) that takes care of the OAuth dance for you.